# Design Pattern Issue

Tags: flex4

My current application has a DataMgr class in which I put everything data-related. This class has grown too big recently and I want to split it into smaller pieces for easier maintenance.

This is what I am thinking about:

- Create an AbstractDataMgr class that will have all the variables that will be accessed everywhere in the application. Example, a usersList ArrayCollection that will contain all users.
- All smaller pieces of DataMgr will extend the AbstractDataMgr. Example, UsersDataMgr class that extends AbstractDataMgr. This way, UsersDataMgr gets to load and populate the usersList in the AbstractDataMgr. Another example, SessionDataMgr class that cares about some playing sessions that take place in my application.

My Questions are:

1. Am I on the right track?
2. I want to put each smaller DataMgr class in a separate module for faster compilation time. This way, when I compile the SessionsModule, it will not look at UsersModule and thus have less compilation time.

And this is my question for which I started this thread for: When inside SessionsModule, how to get users information from the UsersDataMgr (e.g., by calling a function getUserData) without having to import UsersDataMgr in SessionsDataMgr. Because if I imported it, then it will be compiled in the SessionsDataMgr... which I don't want.

I hope I didn't confuse you and I hope I can find some help.

---

## UPDATE 1:

So the basic problem is that I have a large application that was badly designed before I come. Now I am trying to make things better and easier.

Currently, it takes long time to compile the full application right now (about 3-3:30 min.). This is due to multiple issues:
1- Too many files in the framework that need to be checked for changes everytime I compile the application.
2- Some of those files contain large amount of data (e.g., one of the information tables is hard-coded into a big fat array inside a file that is 7.5MB of size).

So currently it is taking me long time to fix bugs and that is because of the long compilation time. So I tried fixing this problem by breaking the application into modules. After creating three modules, I found out that each module's compilation time is also taking a long time (about 2min.)...

In addition to this problem, now instead of one large sized swf, I have 3 other swfs with large sized. So I decided to remove the full framework from these modules, and only include the required files. Everything was looking good at the beginning until I included the DataMgr... after which I had to include all the framework in order to compile without bugs. This is because the DataMgr imports lots of the framework in it.

So my second step in solving this problem is to divide the DataMgr. I like your suggestion, and that is how I was planning to do it... However, I still have one unanswered question:

My intention of having modules and dividing DataMgr is that I don't want to include the full framework in each modules. Rather, only the required files. However, if in the SessionsDataMgr module I would call:

UsersDataMgr.getInstance().getUserInfo( userId );

This means that I have to import UsersDataMgr inside the SessionsDataMgr... which also means (if I understand this correctly) that when compiling UsersDataMgr, the compiler will check all the files of the SessionsModule, but also will check all the files in SessionsDataMgr. This would increase the file size of the swf and will increase compilation time.

- Is my understanding of how things work correctly?
- Is there a solution to this problem to be able to separate both modules completely but be able at some point to user functions from the other module?

Sorry for the long reply, and thank you for you help.

Comment: Okay. I understand your problem scope a bit more clearly. You need to decouple code as much as possible to avoid large amount of compile time dependency and overall complication. The answer you're looking for is reflection. Reflection will allow you to add/remove modules at runtime without recompilation and avoid those checks at compile time. I'm a bit busy now but I will write up some more on it later.

Comment: Thank you. This is the first time I learn about "Reflection". I searched for it online, and got some resources about reflection in .net world. However, I couldn't find any resources about the how to use Reflection in Flex 4. If you have any resources that could help me learn and implement the Reflection pattern please post them. In any case, waiting for your further explanation.

Comment: If what I understand about "Reflection" is correct, then Reflection allows accessing information about an object including method names and variable names... etc. In the "Flex" world, this can be done using the "describeType" function. Just google for "Flex 4 introspection".

Comment: Googling the net for Reflection gives results related to using Reflection in the Factory design pattern. Which sounds reasonable and seems to be good. However, in my case I don't think Factory is a good pattern for me because those dataMgr classes are supposed to be singletons. Its not a good idea to keep creating new instances of the DataMgr class and replicating the data all around the software.

Comment: Hmm... After reading online for a bit, I think my best solution is to use Interfaces. Because thats what I want to do... I want to be able to access UsersDataMgr functions in other modules while not having to recompile the implementation of UsersDataMgr along with the other modules. An Interface would hide the implementation and give me the functionality... exactly what I am looking for. I am still waiting to read your comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it your `DataMgr` class really is trying to do too much. Splitting it up is definitely the way to go.

Abstract classes are intended to provide functionality that is needed across *all* concrete implementations. To provide global data access, the design pattern you're looking for is [**Singleton**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

How you would get user information from the `SessionsModule`:

```
UserDataProvider.getInstance().getAllUsers();
UserDataProvider.getInstance().getUserDetails(UserId:String);
```

Hopefully this puts you on the right track! If you can share a few more details about your application and other responsibilities of the `DataMgr` I would be happy to help you work out a clean and more efficient design.

Comment: hmm... I am not sure how to make a new reply.... is this the way to reply back to you... using these comments...?

Comment: You can use these comments or update your original post. Put a line break and an UPDATE: if you'd like

Comment: Ok, I'll try to fit it here. If not, I'll update the original post.